# Assign name in column based on values from another column

Tags: if-statement, dplyr, paste, assign

I am looking for some help to what seems like a very simple question. Any advice is greatly appreciated! I have created a data frame and I am looking to assign names under one column based on the values in the other column. 
`rdf<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow= 59, ncol=2))'

row names(rdf)<- c(1:35, 37:60)

colnames(rdf)<-c("Unit", "Region")

rdf$Unit<-c(1:35, 37:60)

rdf$Region<- ##Here I want for Units 1:13 <- the region to be East,
for Units 14:25 and 27 the region to be labeled Central,
units 26, 28:43, 45:46, and 58 to be labeled West,
And then Units 44,47:57, and 59:60 to be labeled BC`

Ive been trying case_when or nested if else statements, but I am getting errors relating to a longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and tweak to suit your situation.

```
library(dplyr)
    #The below 2 commands will add a rowid column to the dataframe to uniquely identify the rows
    rdf<- rdf %>% 
      rowid_to_column() %>% 
      # filter(rowid !=36) # filter rows that you do not want.
    
    #assuming csv_rdf contains column named "unit"
    csv_rdf<- csv_rdf %>% 
      rowid_to_column() %>% 
    
    
    main_df<- rdf %>% 
      left_join(csv_df, by="rowid") # this will populate the csv$unit column to the rdf dataframe. The join will be done based on column rowid.
    
    
    main_df<- main_df %>% 
      mutate(region = case_when(
        units >=1 & unique <=13 ~ "East",
        units >=14 & unique <=25 ~ "Central",
        units ==27 ~ "Central", # Add all your conditions below
      
        TRUE ~ 'TBD' # this is kind of catch-all and will need to be re-checked.
      ))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. But I am a bit confused. I will edit my question to get rid of the extra csv. I just use c(1:35, 37:60) to name the rows.

Answer (score 0):

After your **rdf$Unit<-c(1:35, 37:60)** statement, Can you try the following?

```
rdf %>% 
  mutate(Region=case_when(
    Unit >=1 & Unit <=13 ~ 'East',
    Unit >=14 & Unit <=25 ~ 'Central',
    Unit ==27 ~ 'Central',
    Unit ==26 | Unit ==58 ~ 'West',
    Unit >=28 & Unit <=43 ~ 'West',
    Unit >=45 & Unit <=46 ~ 'West',
    Unit ==44 ~ 'BC',
    Unit >=47 & Unit <=57 ~ 'BC',
    Unit >=59 & Unit <=60 ~ 'BC',
    TRUE ~ "Error" # keeping this to later check if all values are populated or not.. Can do count()
  ))
```